# Does a paypal client require expresschekcout implementation to make a direct payment processing call?

Tags: paypal

We are implementing a paypal client application ( not a website) to make directpayment processing calls for incoming requests. 
On researching paypal's documents I found this:please see the 'notes' section

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Merchant/merchant/DCCIntro-outside
and a related stackoverflow question that was not definitively answered.

[Does PayPal include payment integration options that do not require showing PayPal to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949694/does-paypal-include-payment-integration-options-that-do-not-require-showing-payp)

we have an implementation against the sandbox endpoint that successfully makes direct payment processing calls without making expresscheckout calls.

Can anyone confirm that they have successfully implemented the same for a real merchant account?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement direct payment without express checkout, however, PayPal could start sending you notifications that you need to add EC or they'll raise the rates they're charging you for the Pro transactions.  Then if you don't add it for some time period after that they would go ahead and raise the rates on your direct payment transactions accordingly.

If/when this happens, you could contact the account manager for the account (if they have one; if not just call general support) and request that they waive this require for EC.  They will often do so.

All of that said, it's typically recommended to go ahead and include EC as an option for people because your conversion rates will usually increase.